# JPA Audit Timestamp is null on update

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Jhipster project.

I'm trying to use Auditing functionalities by providing my domain with the following annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_date")
private Instant createdDate;

@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "last_upd_date")
private Instant lastUpdDate;

@CreatedBy
@Column(name = "created_by_user")
private String createdByUser;

@LastModifiedBy
@Column(name = "last_upd_by_user")
private String lastUpdByUser;
```

Everything works just fine on INSERTS, all the fields are properly fielded up by the framework, but on update time @CreateDate and @CratedBy are always null.

I would like to understand why this behavior and how to solve it.

Comment: because update and insert are different things

Comment: So i must provide the CreatedDate and CreatedBy values when doing updates?

Comment: What do you mean by "update time CreateDate and CratedBy are always null". Are they in null in the DB?

Comment: Simon Martinelli, I already was able to fix my problem. I wasn't understanding the mechanism by which these annotations works but now I know. My solution is like the code above simply changed this little piece of code        
       CreatedDate
       Column(name = "created_date")
       private Instant createdDate;
       CreatedBy
       Column(name = "created_by_user", updatable = false)
       private String createdByUser;